# Symfony2: in Twig, pass Request with Render function

Tags: symfony, twig

I understand that using `{% render() %}` automatically forces a new request object to be sent, but im curious if theres a way to pass in the originating request as an argument?

```
{% render('some_action', {'originalRequest': app.request}) %}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything for the controller:

```
public function actionAction($originalRequest = null) 
{
    // $originalRequest ends up just being null
}
```

Im assuming its because of the way the route is setup:

```
some_action:
    pattern: /stuff/
    defaults: { _controller:SomeApp:Controller:action }
```

I'd imagine data like that cant obviously be apart of the URL, so some type of way to pass in data to a renderable URL, anything at all?

**EDIT (Solution)**

The solution was pretty simple in the long run, as Petre Pătraşc below has demonstrated, that in Twig, all I needed to do was invoke the Controller directly, and with that approach I can pass in Objects (Such as a Request object) and Arrays, instead of text values in a URL.
To perform roughly the same idea in a controller, utilizing the `forward()` method from the router, will allow similar effects without needing to redirect the user to another page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for this:

```
{% render "MyBundle:Controller:someAction" with { 'originalRequest' : app.request } %}
```

Comment: I finally came across my answer just as you posted this haha this was the ticket though! Not using the Router, just invoking the controller directly

Comment: I'm curious, are you talking about using forward() or otherwise? It would be nice to update the original question with your solution, as it may be an edge-case and help someone!

Answer (score 8):

use the render function as a result

```
{{ render(controller('MyBundle:ControllerName:example', {'originalRequest': app.request})) }}
```

and then in your controller

```
public function exampleAction(Request $originalRequest)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Interesting to note the method's parameter name has to be the same, too

Answer (score -1):

Since Symfony 2.4 you can access the original request via the request_stack.  This avoids the need to create a new method parameter.

```
function exampleAction() {
  $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
  //do something
}
```

> Use this carefully as it makes your sub-requests incompatible with ESIs/reverse proxies (where a sub-request is also a master request) http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with this answer before down voting so I can approve it.