# Symfony3: in Twig, pass Request with Render function

Tags: php, request, symfony

this question was asked for Symfony 2 as well and answered. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326839/symfony2-in-twig-pass-request-with-render-function)

the problem now is that there is no {% render %} Tag in Symfony 3.

```
    {{ render(url('simpleSearch'), {'originalRequest' : app.request}) }}
```

this is my try. it render a form in the action and this should show at a position in all actions. the form works and also the rendering, but the form got no request informations cause in the deep of the render() function there is this code

```
$subRequest = Request::create($uri, 'get', array(), $cookies, array(), $server);
```

this create a blank request and pass it to the rendering action.

Did someone know how i can get the original request like in symfony 2?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got a solution,

you cant get the information to the render function BUT to the url function.

it should look like this

```
{{ render(url('simpleSearch', app.request.query.all)) }}
```

the url funtion only allows an array so .all is a possible solution to get the information in the sub action