# Twig include view file with controller

Tags: php, twig

I have small PVP MVC Framework created by me & I choose Twig for template things. Now the thing when I'm requesting **example.com/home** it's loading the Home controller that render the **home.html** file.

but now I need to include my sidebar into that **home.html** & my side bar rendered using Sidebar controller and how can I invoke the controller rather than just including the **sidebar.html** in twig ? is there any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: in Twig, pass Request with Render function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326839/symfony2-in-twig-pass-request-with-render-function)

Comment: @DarkBee any idea how OpenCart include header by just adding {{ header }} ?

Comment: No I'm sorry, don't have any experience on how `OpenCart` works